# Do any of these Steam software titles run without internet connection?

Tags: macos, games

I'm having difficulties playing games without a live connection to the internet (actually to the steam servers).

Is this a configuration issue or a limitation in the following game titles:

- [Tomb Raider 2013](http://store.steampowered.com/app/203160/)
- [PAYDAY 2](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620)
- [Dead Island](http://steamcommunity.com/app/91310)

I'm hoping to host multiplayer games with my friends without needing Wi-Fi or LAN that connects to the Internet or an external / central game server.

Answer (score 4):

On the Steam website (through the links you listed) the only one listing "broadband internet connection" as a requirement is TR 2013. The other two have no requirements for internet connection indicated.

That said, I have not played any of those games so I cannot certify that the specifications are correct. But I would think they are pretty careful with those, given all the debate going on regarding internet connection requirements for gaming.

On the other hand, I am quite sure that if you want to host multiplayer games with your friends you DO need some kind of LAN connection (wi-fi or wired).